# How do synchronous generator operates at no load?

Tags: generator, synchronous

What will be the effect on the generator when it is operated at no load?

Comment: What effect are you asking about? It will demand torque from the power source to overcome its own frictional and internal losses.

Comment: You need to provide more context for the question. There are numerous synchronous generator types. Please be more specific.

Comment: You need to add context.

Answer (score 1):

When a synchronous generator is operating, something is turning the rotor and something is providing the rotor with a magnetic field. The magnetic field is rotating through the stator conductors and generating voltage. If nothing is connected to the stator, the there is voltage at the stator terminals but no current is flowing. The stator terminal voltage is AC voltage, but other than the fact that the voltage is AC, the stator is much like a battery on a shelf doing nothing, but ready to supply current as soon as a load is connected.

In a permanent-magnet synchronous generator, the losses at no-load are friction, aerodynamic drag (windage), reluctance torque, hystereses and eddy-current losses. A wound-field synchronous generator has additional losses associated with producing the field excitation. Large machines may have additional losses due to the operation of cooling, lubrication, monitoring and protection systems.